# Will iOS apps that are just UIWebView's be rejected?

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

Are apps that are simply UIWebViews (or the Phonegap equivalent) that point at a remote URL subject to rejection from the App store based on that fact alone?

If not outright, what mistakes are easy to make in such a situation that could cause an app to be rejected?

Comment: Ask Apple. We cannot guarantee that they will reject or deny an app.

Comment: I've seen such an app (by a big bank) rejected on the grounds that it doesn't offer anything substantial compared to the plain website in the browser.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for [the App Stores proposal on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores).

Comment: I don't think apple will answer that. Just ask yourself reasonably if your usage is appropriate.

Comment: @hop Would that be a WebUIView app or an actual Objective-C app?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As per section 4.2 of the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/), yes, this kind of app will be rejected.

> **4.2 Minimum Functionality**
>   Your app should include features, content, and UI that elevate it beyond a repackaged website. If your app is not particularly useful, unique, or “app-like,” it doesn’t belong on the App Store. If your App doesn’t provide some sort of lasting entertainment value, it may not be accepted.

Answer (score 5):

@Moshe is correct with pointing out what they SAY, but what they do is a completely different story as we all know. I think it depends on the reviewer that you get, and the mood they are in! Take a look at this example.

KSL app is just their mobile website wrapped in a Web view with a back and forward button, and its in the store.

Their mobile site: http://m.ksl.com/

Their App Link: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ksl.com/id363278608?mt=8

**Update:** KSL now has an updated app, which is an actual app... so my example no longer pertains to them.

Comment: This app still is https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/arc-heitinga-toernooi/id961449214?mt=8