# Titanium - Application having just webview gets rejected?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, app-store-connect, titanium-mobile

I have created an demo application in Titanium for ipad that contains just a single webview. And this webview loads a url that is large tool for drawing, scaling and other tones of features. Are there any chances of application getting rejected. As per my knowledge application containing just a webview would get rejected. If yes then is there any features that could be integrated which ensures that app doesn't get kicked off from app store.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will iOS apps that are just UIWebView's be rejected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735476/will-ios-apps-that-are-just-uiwebviews-be-rejected)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its surely reject by the apple. If web pages are specifically design for the application and thats simple putting in your website into an application, then application will be accepted. You don't put such kind of application which AppStore that are't needed.
Web browser is access same content.

Comment: thanks for your response Jayesh. But there exists any way or lets say any feature that we could integrate so that app is not rejected ? In short i want that same tool to be accessed using app.

Comment: For introducing your application, AppStore is good place. so you can add some native feature like twitter integration or do any other stuff. I hope they accept your application.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jayesh. And surely post result when we submit application to appstore which would surely help others too.