# Can Apple reject my application if it open HTML5 games in WebView?

Tags: ios, html, web-applications, webview, app-store

Can Apple reject my application if it run HTML5 games in WebView?

I develop native app. One screen will contain list with data retrieved from server. Any item run HTML5 game in IOS WebView. I reed guidelines but i`m not sure in this case.

Maybe somebody can provide any published examples with the same behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am 100% sure your app will be rejected, as apple say [here in point no. 2.12](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/). And also check [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421002/app-rejected-from-apple-app-store-because-uiwebview-need-some-advice) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735476/will-ios-apps-that-are-just-uiwebviews-be-rejected). There are lots of apps which will rejected because they are using webView to show HTML or simply load dynamic urls.

If you want your app will pass, you need to add some component natively means mix of native and webView app can be pass. I have develop an app with mix of native and webView and that was passed without any issue.

Comment: can you give me a exmaple? please, im trying to upload using cordoba, and i cant :S thankyou!